# best practice for disabling products: status vs visibility

Tags: magento

What are the differences in disabling disable products via product status and product visibility?
I have read that product status is better, but why exactly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It belongs on [magento.se].

Comment: sorry, didn't know that there certain subdomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A disabled product will not be visible anywhere on the site and cannot be purchased.

A Not Visible product will not be visible on the site but can be purchased (as a simple product of a configurable, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could you please point us to where this is documented?